# Why my application can not find class 'com.google.gson.Gson' on the OnCreate method?

Tags: android, json, gson

I want to use Gson to parse my JSON, I've added Gson library into my project. It's all fine when I compile it, but when I run it, I get error message log says

```
Could not find class 'com.google.gson.Gson', referenced from method report.weeklyflash.WeeklyFlashIdActivity.onCreate
```

here is the code that use Gson:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import report.weeklyflash.ReportResult;
import report.weeklyflash.ReportResults;



public class WeeklyFlashIdActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

    System.out.println("oncreate");

    final TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.headerTable);

    InputStream is = null;
    String json = "";

    //http get content
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://10.80.3.73/webservice/Service1.svc/json/weeklyflash/my");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }


    ReportResults reports = new Gson().fromJson(json, ReportResults.class);
    List<ReportResult> results = reports.getGetReportResult();
//bla..blaa.bblaa..
```

for more detail review, here is my full code:
[My Activity code](http://www.pastie.org/4168954)
[My ReportResult Class code](http://www.pastie.org/4168964)
[My ReportResults Class code](http://www.pastie.org/4168969)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you put the gson.jar in the `libs` directory.  As of ADT17 all external library jars must go there.

The good news is you just drop them in there and the tools take care of adding them to the project.

Oh, that directory needs to be on the same level as `src` and `assets`, etc.

Comment: I've drop .jar in libs directory as you said, then what I should to do next?

Comment: Do a project -> clean and then run your app.  If necessary, remove the old references to the library from when you loaded it in manually.

Comment: it works :) now that error message has gone..but I get new error and I think it's coming from my coding, may you help me again for my new error?

Comment: Sure, post a new.question though as it's a new issue.  I'll have a look when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Make "libs" folder in root of your project where "src"&"assets" folders are kept, put jar files in it, thats all. Now you can use them. Make sure you undo all changes you tried to make it. :)